# Using KeyPathComparator in SwiftUI with Realm Objects

Tags: sorting, swiftui, realm

I am showing a Realm object collection `realmobjects = Results<Object>` in a SwiftUI Table on MacOS.

```
Table(realmobjects, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sorting)
```

How can I use the KeyPathComparator that comes from the $sorting binding to sort with the Realm objects?
As in:

```
realmobjects = realm.objects(Object.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "property", ascending: true)
```

Is it possible to use a Swift KeyPathComparator in the byKeyPath of this Realm sorted function?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
@State private var sorting = [KeyPathComparator(\Object.property)]
```

Comment: In the actual sorting of the objects, if I use `realmobjects.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator)`, it returns an Array of the results.  I want to leave it a Results<objects> realm collection if possible to keep them live.    `realmobjects.sorted(byKeyPath: "property")` returns a Results<objects> collection.  But the SwiftUI Table gives a KeyPathComparator, not a KeyPath.  Is it possible to convert somehow between them?